# How can I make it so my integer from earlier change numbers if something happens?

Tags: java, if-statement, int

I am in a basic computer programming class in High School, and my teacher is no help. I want to make 3 numbers entered by the user to change to 5 if the total is greater than 15. So far I've learned:

**if (g + h + i > 15)

else**

I've also learned   **int g = console.nextInt();**  to get the user to type a number.

What I can't figure out is how to get all 3 integers entered by the user to change to 5 if their total greater than 15. I can get text to appear saying the number 5 or that all numbers are now 5, but i want the text from earlier to change. Is this possible?

Thanks so much for the help. I know this is probably a very easy thing to do, but I appreciate it none the less.

Comment: What is the expected final output of your program?  I mean, we can give you code for what you are asking, but it would seem somewhat pointless without a goal in mind.

Comment: *but i want the text from earlier to change* You want what text where to change? From what to what?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int g = console.nextInt();
int h = console.nextInt();
int i = console.nextInt();

if (g + h + i > 15)
{
    g=5;
    h=5;
    i=5;
}
```

Comment: That changed the value of the variable, so if I had the variable show up again it would be 5, but it did not change the numbers that were originally typed by the user. I need those numbers to change to 5.

Comment: Where do you want to change numbers? In the terminal/command window? To do this you need to print special escape sequences which control the cursor of the terminal window. Not all terminal windows support this and there are multiple standards. Java supports none of them out of the Box. A proper keyword to search for in case of Linux/Unix is "ncurses".

Comment: Yes. In the terminal window, after typing a number, it shows up on the screen. I need that number to change. I guess there's not much I can do. Thanks anyway for helping out.